# symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libsvn_subr-1.so.0: undefined symbol: apr_atomic_xchgptr

Tags: linux, svn

i install svn using yum

yum install mod_dav_svn subversion

Now when i running svn command, i am getting the following problem

symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libsvn_subr-1.so.0: undefined symbol: apr_atomic_xchgptr

can you please help to fix this problem as i am unable to checkout my code.

Answer (score -1):

Well the subversion you installed with `yum` should be in `/usr` so the libraries in `/usr/local` that are causing your problem are presumably from a different version that was compiled from source.

If you don't need them any more then the easiest solution is problem just to remove all traces of subversion from `/usr/local` and it's subdirectories.